# Arguments for philistinism?

Tags: aesthetics

Friend of mine got into *The Magic Mountain*. Me, I was too busy welding rocks and other such worldly things, closest I get to literature is writing "[insert something witty here]," keeping authors in prompts. Gotta do my part.

The Wikipedia page describes Castorp as a philistine, and of course Wikipedia also takes care of edu-mah-cating me on what a philistine is, past a slur. It just sounds incredibly based? Doesn't seem like anybody argues for it, though, as opposed to philosophers arguing for amorality, egoism, or pseudo-philosophers like Evola preaching that we should all be saddling jungle cats.

Am I completely misunderstanding what it means to be a philistine, or is it just that anybody who would waste their time writing books would obviously have nothing good to say about us?

NOTE: I added "aesthetics" as the tag because I couldn't post without it. I have no idea whether this actually applies, since who the hell is dumb enough to trust Wikipedia articles?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're surprised that no-one who believes that intellectual arguments are a waste of time has written down an intellectual argument for intellectual arguments being a waste of time? And dismayed that you can't find intellectual arguments about intellectual arguments being a waste of time because you're a person who doesn't care about intellectual arguments?

Answer (score 2):

People don't often argue about their beliefs while using a pejorative term for themselves. eg, Conspiracy theorists call themselves "critical freethinkers", the bad-mannered call themselves "brutally honest", and rambling lunatics call themselves [insert group you don't like].  As you read in wikipedia, "Philistinism" was invented as an insult.

A "Philistine" might call himself an anti-intellectual, pragmatist, hedonist, nihilist or a combination of other things... If they had the inclination to think about it, as g s has nicely pointed out. There's plenty of arguments for ideas we might associate with philistinism, but you won't find a book called, "why being a boring, lazy jack-a**" is great.

Comment: So are there any good philosophy books from anti-intellectuals, pragmatists, combinations of all that and the rest you mentioned?

Comment: eh, they're kinda broad topics, I'm not knowledgeable enough for good recommendations. I like some of William James - you might like this: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/5116/5116-h/5116-h.htm#link2H_4_0004

Answer (score 1):

The main argument in favour of philistinism is that you don't waste hours of your life scanning and contributing to a philosophy website.